# Restangular and IE below 10 - Access Denied

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, restangular

I am using Restangular pretty heavily and doing my final testing when I discovered that I get `access denied` in IE lower than 10. I looked around and found some older posts about using Angular's `$http` may work. Does anyone know how to make this work with Restangular?

Comment: how do you authenticate etc?

Comment: I am not doing any authentications atm with Restangular.

Comment: restangular uses `$http` under the bonnet. you can always test if it works using `$http.get(url)`.

Comment: I should also mention, my `ng-include` not working either!

Comment: did you follow the ie guidelines? https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie